# How to convert an arrayList.toString() into an actual arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

In my software, since there is no `Array` data type in `SQLite`, I saved my `ArrayList` as a `String`. Now I need to use my array and want to convert it back to an ArrayList. How can I do it?

Here an example :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("name1");
list.add("name2");
list.add("name3");
list.add("name4");
list.add("name5");
list.add("name6");

String newList = list.toString();
System.out.println(newList);
```

Result: `[name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6]`

So now how can I convert this into an `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: `list` is already an `ArrayList<String>` so what do you mean?

Comment: I don't think you want to use `toString`, but `toArray` instead

Comment: It might also be useful to look up [ArrayList Serializing](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-serialize-arraylist-in-java/).

Comment: will list as blob in sql be a bad option ?

Comment: If any of your strings contain commas, the toString() conversion is lossy and there is no simple reliable way to recover the original array.

Comment: You should beware with using `toString()` for serialisation. If you add `"firstname, lastname"` to your list it is impossible to know if it should be deserialised as `["firstname, lastname"]` or `["firstname", "lastname"]` since `toString()` will output `"[firstname, lastname]"` for both.

Comment: @SrinathGanesh well I am not sure. I thought about about the fact that maybe the array becomes too big for a cell in database but I guess there is no other option to transfer an array to a DB.

Comment: @Dan: fix your database model instead. This should be modeled using a one-to-many relation.

Comment: @Raniz Well, in the array I will keep file paths. For example: `C://Document/music.mp3` but you are right. Having a comma in a file name is allowed and that can stop my software. :/ I guess I have look for a different way for storing arrays in databases. Thanks for mentioning tho.

Comment: @raniz do you mean having a separate table for each arraylist and link that to a specific cell of the main table?

Comment: Sort of, you have one table for your main objects (those that contain the lists) and one that contains all items in all lists as separate rows. Each row in the second table contains a reference to the row in the first table where it's owning object is stored (and it's index in the list if order is important). To re-assemble the object you first load the object from the first table and then all it's list items from the second table.

Comment: @Raniz That's really helpful. I need to try it and see if it worth to impeliment it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this should work :

```
Arrays.asList(newList.substring(1, newList.length() - 1).replaceAll("\\s", "").split(","));
```

- Take the string, remove the first and last bracket.
- Remove each spaces.
- Split by comma as delimiter, collect as list.

Note that if really you have to do this for a project, then there is something wrong in your code design. However, if this is just for curiosity purpose then this solution would work.

---

**After testing**

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("name1");
list.add("name2");
list.add("name3");
list.add("name4");
list.add("name5");
list.add("name6");

String newList = list.toString();                
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList(newList.substring(1, newList.length() - 1).replaceAll("\\s", "").split(","));

System.out.println(myList);
```

would compile properly and print :

```
[name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6]
```

---

**Edit**

As per your comments, if really you want your variable to be an `ArrayList<String>` instance then you could pass the list to `ArrayList` constructor :

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(newList.substring(1, newList.length() - 1).replaceAll("\\s", "").split(",")));
```

You can't cast directly as `Arrays.asList` use it own builtin `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I have the output as an ArrayList<String> ?

Comment: @user2357112 Rollbacked to my previous version. Actually when seeing the other answer, I tought it allowed this possibility which is obviously not the case.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible to do without ambiguity.  Consider:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("name1, name2");
list.add("name3, name4");
list.add("name5");
list.add("name6");

String newList = list.toString();
System.out.println(newList);

Result: [name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6]
```

In order to accurately recover the original elements in the general case, your string format must be smarter than `ArrayList.toString()`.  Consider a pre-defined way of encoding lists of strings, perhaps a JSON array, which would result in something like this for my example:

```
["name1, name2", "name3, name4", "name5", "name6"]
```

JSON also defines how to handle strings with quotes via escaping and/or use of alternate string start/end characters `'` and `"`:

```
["he said, 'hello'", 'she said, "goodbye"', 'I said, "it\'s raining"']
```

(I also agree with other commenters that your database design should be reconsidered, but wanted to provide a clear answer illustrating the issues with string encodings of lists.)

Comment: Thanks Indeed. That's a good idea. I guess GSON from Google can do this. I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Then it the method that only accepts strings would be able to add a case where something like this were passed in?

```
methodThatOnlyAllowsStrings((Object)list);
```